# How to use this function what 'View group' on android-studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I don't have enough skills to code. But I have to make this program. so please help me...
I want to make function to slide the screen sideways in Android but it isn't working what I made. how can I do? please tell me.

**PS**: I want to use `'View group'` and this code is on the `MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val sv = SlidingView(this)
    val v1 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.t1, null)
    val v2 = View.inflate(this, R.layout.t2, null)
    sv.addView(v1)
    sv.addView(v2)
    setContentView(sv)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are overriding your `SlidingView` with `activity_main`, you are calling `setContentView` twice and the latest call overrides the first one, so your view gets replaced with what's in layout `activity_main`, if you do not have anything in `activity_main`, do remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

***or***

if you want `SlidingView` to be a part of `activity_main`, then add it to `activity_main` xml instead.

Comment: oh really thank u.... I was able to solve this problem for u. but I have one more question, how about use 'ViewPager2' function instead 'View group'?  what about think?

Comment: Glad I could help, please accepta nd upvote the answer if it helped :)